# Issue with bundler or gems I can't work out when I type 'bundle exec rake spec'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rspec, bundler, railstutorial.org

I'm trying to run the command

```
bundle exec rake spec
```

but it returns the following:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:2
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/setup.rb:1:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/setup.rb:1
```

There seems to be a problem with the requiring of gems but I do have gems running on my machine,

```
$ gem -v
```

returns 1.8.5

I don't know if it's to do with where the files are stored? When I run

```
$ gem list -d bundler
```

I get

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.0.21)
Authors: André Arko, Terence Lee, Carl Lerche, Yehuda Katz
Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/bundler
Homepage: http://gembundler.com
Installed at: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8

The best way to manage your application's dependencies
```

And in IRB:

```
irb(main):001:0> require "bundler"
LoadError: no such file to load -- bundler
from (irb):1:in `require'
from (irb):1
from :0
```

I've tried toggling between different versions of Rails 3.0 (3.0.9 and 3.0.8),
I've tried uninstalling and installing Bundler and been over to RubyGems to check if there were any further dependencies I needed but nothing seems to be working.

I'm using Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and Ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin10]

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using ruby 1.9.x. The 1.8 branch won't be supported for much longer in Rails.

Consider using http://beginrescueend.com

Try with ruby 1.9, I suspect that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I actually had RVM installed but it wasn't working the way I'd have expected it to, I think I had something altogether wrong with my Rails installation which I'm in the process of reinstalling.